# In-App Purchases Extremely slow

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have working In-App Purchases in my app, they are just one-shot non consumable purchases. They fully work and the implementation is even live in the app store.
However, at seemingly random times, when a user attempts to purchase the response from Apple is EXTREMELY SLOW, like on the order of 30+ seconds over Wi-Fi on a 100Mbps network or on LTE/3G. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with connectivity, it simply takes that long for Apple's response to come.

Here is the basic code that creates this prompt and handles the response:

```
// User has decided to buy a sticker pack
- (void) promptToBuyPack:(StickerPack *)pack {
    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        if([products valueForKey:pack.packID]) {
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:[products valueForKey:pack.packID]];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
        }
        else {
            nlog(@"User attempted to buy a pack that iTunes does not recognize");
        }

    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can not make purchases" message:@"Your device does not have purchases enabled. Please enable them in order to proceed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [a show];
    }
}



- (void) grantProductAccess:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    // Store purchase in user defaults
    nlog(@"Bought product: %@", productIdentifier);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void) tellUserPurchaseIsComplete {
    UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Complete" message:@"Your pack is now unlocked, Enjoy!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [a show];
    [a release];
}

- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        BOOL canFinishTransaction = NO;
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                canFinishTransaction = YES;
                [self grantProductAccess:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
                [self tellUserPurchaseIsComplete];
                if(iPad)
                    [FlurryAPI logEvent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Purchased %@ on iPad",transaction.payment.productIdentifier]];
                else
                    [FlurryAPI logEvent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Purchased %@ on iPod",transaction.payment.productIdentifier]];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                nlog(@"Transactin failed");
                canFinishTransaction = YES;
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                nlog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored");
                canFinishTransaction = YES;
                [self grantProductAccess:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
                break;
            default:
                nlog(@"SKPaymentTransactionDefault");
                break;
        }

        // Remove from payment queue
        if(canFinishTransaction)
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a reason / solution for your problem? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I have not fully identified the problem, but what I've done in the next version of my app is switch the entire store system to use MKStoreKit. I have no idea what caused the problems or if this even contains a fix. Effectively I just "rewrote" everything so hopefully it works now. The app is in review as we speak, so I'll report back on if it helped.

Comment: The issue seems to have been resolved using MKStoreKit!

Comment: I know this is an old question but can you post part of your code in the answers. I am currently using store kit and it is very slow and sometime doesn't even load.

Comment: the same situation here. btw, mkstorekit uses storekit, so no idea why it helped anyone.